# NSLog sending messages to system.log in macOS Sierra

Tags: nslog, macos-sierra

After updating to macOS Sierra my fairly old and previously ok application has stopped sending `NSLog` messages directly to Console. Instead I have to view the messages in system.log.

Is this expected behaviour, or is there some migration I need to perform to restore the old behaviour?